NestJs Hanging other than get requests with http-proxy-middleware
whenever i try to request this localhost:3000/dashboard it not getting anything only blank screen nothing is happeining
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

@Injectable()
export class ProxyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8001',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/dashboard': '/',
      },
    });

    // Explicitly define the next call as a callback function to handle errors if any.
    return proxy(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      next();
    });
  }
}`


this is proxy middleware code where i need to access that url(8001) with route /dashboard
// app.module.ts
import { Module, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProxyMiddleware } from './proxy.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [],
})
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(ProxyMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: 'dashboard', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
 }

this is module.ts code for proxy 
//main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
async function bootstrap () {

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Application is running on: http://localhost:3000');
}

bootstrap();

this is main.ts code main entry of my nestjs application `in proxy middleware my ui is present within target url i am unable to get or post methods with this middleware ...............
Is there any other ways to over come this problem

what if you do use = createProxyMiddleware(...) in your middleware class instead of implementing that wrapper for ProxyMiddleware#use?

before this implementation i followed as you answered but result is same like not found and blank screen
